# Permutation with max length parameter

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm writing an function to create all possible permutation with max length limitation, and each item in array can only be used once.

The original permutation code as follows:

```
function permutations(list)
{
    // Empty list has one permutation
    if (list.length == 0)
        return [[]];

    let result = [];

    for (let i=0; i<list.length; i++)
    {
        // Clone list (kind of)
        let copy = Object.create(list);

        // Cut one element from list
        let head = copy.splice(i, 1);

        // Permute rest of list
        let rest = permutations(copy);

        // Add head to each permutation of rest of list
        for (let j=0; j<rest.length; j++)
        {
            let next = head.concat(rest[j]);
            result.push(next);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

How best to add this max length parameter to create unique combination result? I added `maxLength`. But in recursion stuck on where to best implement this parameter.

Comment: Just add it as param to your function and pass it along if you call it again or make a "global" variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript permutation generator with permutation length parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305747/javascript-permutation-generator-with-permutation-length-parameter)

Answer (score 5):

From a minimalist point of view, stop the recursion not when you have shrinked list from its size but when maxLength element have been taken from the list.

```js
function permutations(list, maxLength)
{
    // Empty list has one permutation
    if (maxLength == 0)
        return [[]];

    let result = [];

    for (let i=0; i<list.length; i++)
    {
        // Clone list (kind of)
        let copy = Object.create(list);

        // Cut one element from list
        let head = copy.splice(i, 1);

        // Permute rest of list
        let rest = permutations(copy, maxLength-1);

        // Add head to each permutation of rest of list
        for (let j=0; j<rest.length; j++)
        {
            let next = head.concat(rest[j]);
            result.push(next);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
const maxLength = 4
console.time('by cp')
var r = permutations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], maxLength)
console.timeEnd('by cp')
console.log(r)
```

---

However, a similar approach but slightly more performant is to avoid copying the array for every "try" and only copy it when a solution is found

```js
function permutations2(iList, maxLength)
{
    const cur = Array(maxLength)
    const results = []
    function rec(list, depth = 0) {
        if (depth == maxLength) {
            return results.push(cur.slice(0))
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
            cur[depth] = list.splice(i, 1)[0]
            rec(list, depth + 1)
            list.splice(i, 0, cur[depth])
        }
    }
    rec(iList)
    return results;
}
console.time('cp on solution')
var r = permutations2([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 4)
console.timeEnd('cp on solution')
console.log(r)
```